# save bricked xt1527 with disabled usb debugging

Tags: usb-debugging, motorola, motorola-moto-e

I have a surnia xt1527 which was bricked because of some mistakes I made when trying to make a factory reset (I don't remember what I did because it was a while ago). The device has usb debugging disabled and hence I can't use adb tools. I also can't flash the stock firmware or a custom recovery from an sd card because the recovery won't let me access the sd card. Is there anything I can do to save the phone even though usb debugging is disabled? thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: [Restore Moto E (2015) Stock Firmware](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/general/guide-restore-moto-e-2015-stock-firmware-t3044936)

Comment: @Robert yes and I get preflash validation failed error when I run flash partition gpt.bin

Comment: GPT is the partition table. if validation fails you probably try to flash mismatching partition layout

Comment: @alecxs I get preflash validation failed almost everywhere, not only with gpt but also with the recovery, bootloader and the system.img_sparsechunk files also, I don't know why :( I'm trying to flash 6.0 which is the latest version so it's not a problem of downgrading

Comment: fastboot flash works only when bootloader is unlocked (i don't know for mfastboot) you should try QPST

Comment: @alecxs but qpst needs usb debugging doesn't it?

Comment: no. it uses EDL mode

Comment: @alecxs ok i'm trying to use it but the program doesn't recognize my phone, i've been trying to save this phone for ever I don't think what else to do haha, thanks for answering